# Como carregar um arquivo HTML dentro de uma DIV no zend-framework3

Tags: php, jquery, zend-framework-3

Estou trabalhando em uma ferramenta de email marketing e preciso carregar um template HTML dentro de uma DIV na view. Estou usando o zend-framework3. Eu tentei usar a função .load(), mas está dando erro 500. Alguém pode me ajudar??

Eu estou usando a seguinte função:

```
$('#carregaTemplate').click(function(){

    var qtdProdutos = $('#qtdProdutos').val();

    $(function(){
        if( qtdProdutos == 1 ) {
            $('#arquivoHtml').load('templates/sem_produtos.html');
        }
        if( qtdProdutos == 2 ) {
            $('#arquivoHtml').load('templates/dois_produtos.html');
        }
        if( qtdProdutos == 3 ) {
            $('#arquivoHtml').load('templates/tres_produtos.html');
        }
        if( qtdProdutos == 4 ) {
            $('#arquivoHtml').load('templates/quatro_produtos.html');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Erro 500 é no lado do servidor, verifique as rotas, veja no console como está montando o endereço para os templates e tente acessá-los diretamente pela barra de endereços.

Comment: Verifiquei as rotas e tentei acessar diretamente também, o navegador exibe a mensagem de que não pode atender a solicitação. Tentei usar um <iframe> obtive o mesmo erro 500. Creio que o zend exige uma outra forma para renderizar arquivos HTML. Estou pesquisando, porém não encontrei nada ainda... @Leandro Angelo

Comment: Não adianta colocar em iFrame, você precisa adicionar uma rota para os arquivos estáticos para que ele a ignore sem tentar achar uma controller e uma action para a requisição

Comment: Dê uma olhada aqui https://blog.eduonix.com/web-programming-tutorials/static-pages-in-zend-framework/

Comment: Obrigado @Leandro Angelo. A partir do blog indicado consegui chegar a resolução do problema. Utilizei o exemplo contido aqui https://olegkrivtsov.github.io/using-zend-framework-3-book/html/en/Routing/Regex_Route_Type.html

Comment: seria interessante você postar uma resposta explicando como você resolveu. Essa informação pode ser muito útil para outros usuários que venham a esbarrar no mesmo problema

Answer (score 0):

Após muita pesquisa e a contribuição dos caros amigos aqui do stack, consegui resolver o problema da seguinte maneira:

-criei uma rota do tipo Regex. Esse tipo de rota permite renderizar páginas estáticas. Veja exemplo aqui: https://olegkrivtsov.github.io/using-zend-framework-3-book/html/en/Routing/Regex_Route_Type.html

-no controlador, criei a seguinte função responsável por renderizar a página:

```
public function docAction() {
    $pageTemplate = 'email-marketing/template/doc' . $this->params()->fromRoute('page', 'documentation.phtml');

    $filePath = __DIR__ . '/../../view/' . $pageTemplate . '.phtml';        
    if (!file_exists($filePath) || !is_readable($filePath)) {
        $this->getResponse()->setStatusCode(404);
        return;
    }

    $viewModel = new ViewModel([
        'page'=>$pageTemplate
    ]);

    $viewModel->setTemplate($pageTemplate);

    return $viewModel;
}
```

e por fim, a função que carrega a página dentro de uma DIV, no meu caso, ficou assim:

function carregaTemplate() {

```
    var qtdProdutos = $('#qtdProdutos').val();

    if( qtdProdutos == 1 ) {
        $('#arquivoHtml').load( "<?= $this->url('doc', ['page' => 'pagina']) ?>", function( response, status, xhr ){
            if( status == "error" ) {
                var msg = "Desculpe, ocorreu um erro: ";
                $('#arquivoHtml').html( msg + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText );
            }
        });
    }
    if( qtdProdutos == 2 ) {
        $('#arquivoHtml').load( "<?= $this->url('doc', ['page' => 'dois_produtos']) ?>", function( response, status, xhr ){
            if( status == "error" ) {
                var msg = "Desculpe, ocorreu um erro: ";
                $('#arquivoHtml').html( msg + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText );
            }
        });
    }
    if( qtdProdutos == 3 ) {
        $('#arquivoHtml').load( "<?= $this->url('doc', ['page' => 'tres_produtos']) ?>", function( response, status, xhr ){
            if( status == "error" ) {
                var msg = "Desculpe, ocorreu um erro: ";
                $('#arquivoHtml').html( msg + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText );
            }
        });
    }
    if( qtdProdutos == 4 ) {
        $('#arquivoHtml').load( "<?= $this->url('doc', ['page' => 'quatro_produtos']) ?>", function( response, status, xhr ){
            if( status == "error" ) {
                var msg = "Desculpe, ocorreu um erro: ";
                $('#arquivoHtml').html( msg + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText );
            }
        });
    }

}
```